# XML list item attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml

i need to create the following in XML:

> ```
> <DATAITEMS>
>   <DATAITEM>ABC</DATAITEM>
>   <DATAITEM>1</DATAITEM>
> </DATAITEMS>
> ```

when i configure my property as:

```
public List<string> DATAITEMS { get; set; }
```

this gives me an output of:

> ```
> <DATAITEMS>
>   <string>ABC</string>
>   <string>1</string>
> </DATAITEMS>
> ```

any idea how can i create collection of DATAITEM instead of string?

thanks

Comment: How are you currently converting the list into XML?

Comment: well are you serializing your class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope you are trying to serialize your data, if so you have to use `XmlArrayItem` to control array item names.

```
 [XmlArray("DATAITEMS")]
 [XmlArrayItem("DATAITEM")]
 public List<string> DATAITEMS { get; set; }
```

Comment: well i was trying serialization now a days :P.

Comment: it would really help other if you can edit your question to answer Cameron's and my question :).